# Why do some contacts on the favorites screen on Phone.app show initials and others an icon?

Tags: ios, phone.app

In iOS 7 the contacts in my favorites screen in Phone.app that don't have a photo show either initials or a person icon. Why not just one or the other and what determines which image a contact will get?

I think this is best shown with a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out 3 different situations in which an icon instead of initials is displayed

- emoji in any of the name fields
- The number is a business instead of a person (Thanks Eddie)
- No name in the person or business fields of a contact

I would think that it would still show initials in the first case if the emoji isn't the first letter in any of the name fields but that isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

The icon is displaying because that contact's "name" is entered as a business name, and their "First" and "Last" names are blank.